# bash forgets export variable

Tags: bash, variables, export

I am unable to make even the simplest export of variables, from within scripts, to work in my bash - what am I dooing wrong?

File **test.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $ttt
ttt="fffalse"
export ttt
echo $ttt
```

**bash test :**

```
hpek@hpek:~/temp$ export ttt="tttrue"
hpek@hpek:~/temp$ ./test.sh 
tttrue
fffalse
hpek@hpek:~/temp$ ./test.sh 
tttrue
fffalse
hpek@hpek:~/temp$
```

**Edit:**

I now know from the answers, that this will not work. -but how can make a single variable remembered between processes? Do I need to store it in a file?

Comment: +1 for the title. Bad bash! :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./test.sh` is the same as `bash test.sh`

Each shell script running is, in effect, a [subprocess](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) (child process) of the parent shell.
And subprocess cannot export env-var to it's parent.

---

You can try this（run in the same environment）:

```
. test.sh
```

Comment: "`. test.sh`" is actually working - thanks. What does this mean? that is is run in current shell and not as a child?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen  `. test.sh` is completely equivalent to `source test.sh` which just means that the interpreter takes each line from `test.sh` and runs it in the current environment *as if you had typed it into the current script*.  If you're familiar with `C`, it's somewhat similar to what the preprocessor does when you do `#include "file.h"`.  see this link:  ( http://ss64.com/bash/period.html )

Answer (score 3):

`export` works in the current process and any children spawned afterward; it does not work across process boundaries (parents, existing children, unrelated processes).  The environment behaves like a sort of shadow argument list, not like a filesystem or mailbox.