# Bash variable that outlives the shell script

Tags: bash, shell

We have an issue that I am able to recreate with this simple example.  I have the following sample shell script file, named `SO-shell.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash
export my_var="A quick bown fox"
echo my_var was set to "$my_var"
```

When I run `SO-shell.txt` I get the following output:
`my_var was set to A quick bown fox`

After the script has finished execution, if I execute the following at the shell command line:
`shell> echo "$my_var"`

I don't see anything (i.e. shell variable did not get assigned beyond the lifespan of the shell script)

---

**Q)** How to make a shell variable outlive the lifespan of its defining shell script?

Comment: You can't.  Nor would you want to.  Perhaps you want to source the file rather than execute it.

Comment: Possible duplicate questions: ["Can I export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i), ["bash forgets export variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457725/bash-forgets-export-variable), and ["How to export a variable in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307120/how-to-export-a-variable-in-bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The export and ‘declare -x’ commands allow parameters and functions to be added to and deleted from the environment.

[Bash Reference Manual - Environment](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment)

By using export command, basically you are declaring the variable for this specific process and its child-processes.

However, as workaround you can execute your script in the next way `. SO-shell.tx`

As example:

```
[19:30:50][/]# bash test.sh
my_var was set to A quick bown fox
[19:30:59][/]# echo $my_var

[19:31:11][/]# . test.sh
my_var was set to A quick bown fox
[19:31:15][/]# echo $my_var
A quick bown fox
```

You have more information about this here: [Export variable from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a shell variable outlive the lifespan of its defining shell script?

It's impossible (in normal shell implementations). Because shell variables are stored in memory inside the shell process and after a process dies all process memory is returned to the operating system, all information stored there is lost including the variable.

You can basically use any method of interprocess communication:

- Use a file.

  - Store the variable value to a file from child shell and restore it in parent shell.
  - Store the variable definition (ie. `declare -p my_var`) in the file in child shell and `source` the file in parent shell.
- Output the variable and grab the output in parent shell with command substitution.
- Use a fifo between child and parent shell
- Write your own tooling or your own shell implementation that would for example use shared memory to store the variable.